# SignalR long disconnection timeout on Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service, signalr

I have an ASP .Net Core server app with SignalR. There is also a client app also written with .Net Core and SignalR. The client connects to the server and they work together.

While working in a local development environment everything works as expected but when I deploy my Server app to the Azure App Service I noticed weird behaviour.

When the client disconnects from the server, the event that the client disconnected comes with a huge lag of ~30 seconds. While other calls between the client and the server work normally, we observe the lag only with client disconnection event.

While investigating this issue I came up with solution to reduce the `KeepAliveInterval` in server settings;

```
.AddSignalR(configure =>
{
    configure.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    configure.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = null;
    configure.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    configure.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
});
```

And then the client disconnection event is immediate.

Can someone explain why this issue occurs on Release version on Azure?

The issue did not happen in the local Development environment.

The issue did not happen in the local Release environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `SignalR` Hub `OnReconnected` Event Handler can execute directly after the `OnConnected` but not after the `OnDisconnected` for a given client. The reasons of reconnection without a disconnection is for several ways  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#connection-lifetime-terminology-and-scenarios)

[image]

Physical connections might be slow or there might be interruptions in connectivity. Depending on factors such as the length of the interruption, the transport connection might be dropped. `SignalR` then tries to re-establish the transport connection. Sometimes the transport connection API detects the interruption and drops the transport connection, and `SignalR` finds out *immediately* that the *connection is lost*.

In other scenarios, neither the t`ransport connection API` nor `SignalR` becomes aware immediately that *connectivity has been lost*. For all transports except long polling, the `SignalR client` uses a function called ***keepalive*** to check for loss of connectivity that the transport API is unable to detect. For information about long polling connections, see  here [Timeout and keepalive settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#timeoutkeepalive) l

Refer for more [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#connection-lifetime-terminology-and-scenarios)

Comment: Ok this can explain the timeout, but why this process takes ~30 sec on Azure production environment but is immediate on local dev/release enviro.